# BAT script that sends commands to program it starts

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
ftp my.ip.add.ress
(user id)
(password)
cd /the/directory
send C:/code/project1/*
bye
```

I know you can send Windows `ftp` commands through the command line when you first start it like `-send`, but the question is can I use a .bat script to act interactively with the program it starts?  By default what happens is the first line:

```
ftp my.ip
```

Starts ftp, but the subsequent lines never run until `ftp` exits.

### edit

Another way to phrase this question is "Is it possible to use a .bat file to queue lines of text to feed to `stdin` when `stdin` is next checked for input?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the command shell is not multi-threaded, so there is no way for a batch to continue executing while another interactive shell program is executing within it.

You need to move the FTP commands into their own file, and pass that to the FTP program so it can run them as its own internal script.

```
ftp -s:filename
```

Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the commands will run automatically after FTP starts.

Comment: This answers the specific case of `ftp`, however I'm curious about whether or not its possible to "queue" things in stdin as it were from a .bat file -

Comment: The queue would have to have some way to discriminate when it should and shouldn't feed the next line to stdin. Given that at least some shell programs can continuously accept input, I don't think there's a way around requiring that programs internalize their own batch processing methods (e.g. passing a file to FTP).